# reading shell script output in java (wget)

Tags: java, shell, wget

I'm trying to write a graphical interface for wget.
I can run shell scripts in java and read script's output, but in case of wget the following code won't work.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec("wget someAddress");
        InputStream output = proc.getInputStream();
        int nextByte = output.read();
        while(nextByte != -1){
            System.out.print((char)nextByte);
            nextByte = output.read();
        }
```

so what should I do in order to get percenage of download?

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't want to say it's impossible, but you'll need to write an entire curses library to capture it. It would be significantly easier to [Read Directly from a URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to Stick to a `Wget` from java, you might have to the check the downloading file on disk and do your percentage from the increasing size.

Comment: yeah but it's not all. I'm gonna need the download speed and some other things like that!!

Comment: well, you can always extrapolate the download speed from current size, total size, size left to download and time deltas. (increasing size over period of x unit of time).